# Keep alive UDP socket in background for ios

Tags: ios, udp, voip, cfreadstream

My question is not actually what is the code to keep `UDP` socket alive when application in background but a confusion about the documentation in apple developer site.

According to [apple developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12) if i set `kCFStreamNetworkServiceType` to `kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP` then this socket will be managed specially by system when app in background.

[image]

In [CocoaAsyncSocket library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/blob/master/GCD/GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h) they reported that this settings is not working in `UDP` socket but only in `TCP` socket. I also tested this option for native `CFReadSteam` interface but socket didn't alive when app was in background. But apple developer site never mention it. 
[image]

**Is this true that only tcp socket can keep alive in background or i am making any mistake in my code?**

Comment: I won't tell for Apple and this specific code, but it is worthy to point out that UDP is connectionless protocol. There is no such thing as "keeping alive" in UDP, you keep a live connection and UDP stateless. The name "UDP socket" might be misleading here. Even though your socket can be "connected" - that just means that your OS stores the peer IP address and UDP port number in kernel space, but there is no state being associated with this "connection" to be maintained and, therefore, there is nothing to "keep alive".

Comment: @wick I am sorry that my post confused you. I am actually want to keep open the udp socket(receiver). When application goes to background(in iPhone), system close the socket. So if someone send me data in udp port while my app in background then i can't receive that.

Comment: did you ever get an answer on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Only way is TCP socket for now.